# Varnish with apache on Ubuntu 14

Tags: php, json, apache, ubuntu-14.04, varnish

i have installed Varnish on my Ubuntu server. Already Apache, MySQL and PHP are running on the server.

Application is : PHP and Json working as web services for an iOS and Android app.It a social networking app. the images are loading very slow (Like instagram)
hens i have installed Varnish for server side cache. but when i check the varnish status with http://www.isvarnishworking.com . i am getting below results

> Varnish appears to be responding at that url, but the "Age" header is less than 1.
>
> This means that either, 1) you checked right when Varnish cleared it's cache for that url, or 2) for whatever reason Varnish is not actually serving the content for that url from cache.
>
> If it is the former, just check again and see if you get a more solid confirmation.
>
> If it is the latter, perhaps one of the following is happening:
>
> That url is excluded from the cache on purpose in the Varnish vcl file (in which case, yay! It's working.)
> The application is sending cache headers that are telling Varnish not to serve that content from cache. This means you'll have to fix the cache headers the application is sending to Varnish. A lot of the time those headers are Cache-Control and/or Expires.
> The application is setting a session cookie, which can prevent Varnish from serving content from cache. This means you'll have to update the application and make it not send a session cookie for anonymous traffic.
> Internet Ghosts.

please need some suggestion to setup varnish to my web services.

Comment: You have the clues in the text you pasted. Most probably your application is sending headers or cookies that prevent caching, fix that.

Comment: please let me know if you fixed the issue. i am getting the same thing. i am using varnish on top of craft cms. i did everything from craft cms side but still same thing. thnx in advance.